# Converting recursive formula into non-recursive

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, recursion

I am currently playing around with recursive formulars. The following problem is not taken froma book or course.

Denote by $R_k$ a matrix of dimension $k \times k$ and by $r_k$ a vector of dimension $1 \times k$. Furthermore we are given a lower unittriangular matrix $R_2$ and the recursive formula $R_{k+1} = \begin{pmatrix} R_k & 0 \\ r_kR_k & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. It is easy to compute the matrix $R_3, R_4, R_5...$ one after another, but does there exist a closed formula such that given an integer $n$ one can compute the matrix $R_n$ without computing $R_3, ..., R_{n-1}$?

I already tried computing the sequence and find an explicit description but the therms become very fast very complex: Denote by $r_k^i$ the i-th entry of the vector $r_k$:

$R_2=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\
r_1^1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

$R_3 =\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\
r_1^1 & 1 & 0 \\
r_2^1+r_2^2r_1^1 & r_2^2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

$R_4 =\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
r_1^1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
r_2^1+r_2^2r_1^1 & r_2^2 & 1 & 0\\
r_3^1+r_1^1r_3^2+r_3^3r_2^1+r_3^3r_2^2r_1^1 & r_3^2+r_3^3r_2^2 & r_3^3 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

So far I only see the pattern at the subdiagonals.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please show your work; in particular, your computation of $R_1, R_2, \cdots, R_5.$  Then, please share your thoughts about how you might find the closed form expression if one exists.  Also, please specify your math background-education-level_of_sophistication.  Further, what is the source of the problem?  If from a book/class, which one, and what theorems, previously solved problems or worked examples led up to this problem?  Please do **not** respond with a comment.  Instead, edit your query.  ...see next comment

Comment: Is there some pattern to the $r_k$?

Comment: For a generic discussion of the requirements for a mathSE query, please see [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: There is a pattern behing $r_k$ but with very complex therms that do not explicitely connect to any of the given variables, so I think it is best to ignore this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

WLOG, $R_0=(1)$. Then

$$R_1=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\r&1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$R_2=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\r&1&0\\s+rs'&s'&1\end{pmatrix}$$
$$R_3=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\r&1&0&0\\s+rs'&s'&1&0\\t+rt'+(s+rs')t''&t_1+s't''&t''&1\end{pmatrix}$$

does not seem to lead us anywhere.

Comment: Yes exactly. There is no obvious pattern.

Comment: @samabu: are the $r_k$ completely independent ?

Comment: Yes they are. The matrix $R_k$ is of full rank.